# How to color the rows of a dataframe whose column value is true?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the last column values are either true or false. I want to color only those rows whose last column value is true.  [snap of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRbcV.png)

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.